# can not install shutil library in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, installation

in the python 2.7, I find I can't install the shutil library through pip and easy_install, it said can't find it.How can I install it?

Answer (score 27):

You likely cannot find it, because it is part of the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html). `shutil` has been included in Python since before 2.3.

Answer (score 10):

`shutil` has been in the standard library.Just`import shutil`~